# Нужна ли запятая перед «что»?

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая перед «что»?

*Шакшука — королева среди яичниц. Вы обязательно должны её попробовать! Расскажем(,) что это, как приготовить и красиво подать к столу.*

Comment: Пробовать **её**? Шакшуку, королеву или яичницу? Надо избегать лишних вопросов: должны обязательно это попробовать!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Шакшука — королева среди яичниц. Вы обязательно должны её попробовать! **Расскажем, чтО это, как приготОвить и как красиво подать к столУ.***

1. Запятая нужна. Это классическое сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с однородными придаточными изъяснительными.

Запятая ставится после главного предложения (односоставное, определенно-личное), представленного только сказуемым.

2. Желательно добавить еще одно союзное слово "как", в этом случае предложение звучит более выразительно (каждое из трех придаточных имеет свое ударение).